# change text on click jquery

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<td class="select-cli-numbers"><div class="explanationText" style="cursor:pointer;">Click here to select numbers</div></td>
```

which when toggled, I want to display as
    Click here to hide CLI numbers

my js is as follows, but doesn't work. ANy ideas?

```
$(".select-cli-numbers").toggle(function () {
            $('#cli-numbers').show();
            $(this).text() = "Click here to hide CLI numbers"
    }, function () {
            $('#cli-numbers').hide();
            $(this).text() = "Click here to show CLI numbers"
        });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You’ve just a slight problem with your syntax.

```
$(".select-cli-numbers").toggle(function () {
  $('#cli-numbers').show();
  $(this).children().text("Click here to hide CLI numbers");
}, function () {
  $('#cli-numbers').hide();
  $(this).children().text("Click here to show CLI numbers");
});
```

`text()` takes a text string and sets the element’s text node to that.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This works, however, it gets rid of the <div class="explanationText" style="cursor:pointer;"> surrounding the text

Comment: OK, that’s easy enough to fix. Change your code to `$(this).children().text('…')`

Answer (score 1):

that should be like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".explanationText").toggle(function () {
      $('#cli-numbers').show();
      $(this).text("Click here to hide CLI numbers");
    }, function () {
      $('#cli-numbers').hide();
      $(this).text("Click here to show CLI numbers");
    });


});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `toggle()` function you are using is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/category/deprecated/), I'd go for a click function instead:

```
$(".select-cli-numbers").on('click', function() {
    var msg = $('#cli-numbers').toggle().is(':visible')?'hide':'show';
    $('.explanationText', this).text("Click here to "+msg+" CLI numbers");
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/cGQR5/1/)